# https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token : Connection Timeout

Tags: java, twitter-oauth, spring-social

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token":Connection timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:607)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:493)
    at org.springframework.social.oauth1.OAuth1Template.exchangeForToken(OAuth1Template.java:192)

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem with a Python program.

POST https://www.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

Request headers are similar to this:

```
headers= {'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_nonce="4df3da1d-18e1-4ea7-a9ac-03374483d6f2", oauth_timestamp="1486140325", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="*****************", oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%example.com%3A8888%2Fauth%2Ftwitter", oauth_signature="***********************"'}
```

Result:

```
tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 599: Timeout
```